# ! File ended while scanning use of \frac

Tags: pdf, fractions, german, physics

> > I did not change anything since last time, but I am getting the error
> > message:
> > ! File ended while scanning use
> > of \frac Btw I am a total noob when it comes to LATEX! I've already checked the questions with the same error but they didn't help at all. My goal is to display the code in the pdf-viewer. This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}%müsste das Design sein
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, locale = DE}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{esvect}

%Mathe- Makros
    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 
    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}

%Titelseite

\date{Versuchsdurchführung: 23.09.2020}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}
\begin{center}
\text{ Gruppe 3}\\
\text{Versuchsleiterin: Lena Neuffer}
\end{center}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\section{Einleitung/Versuchsziel}
In diesem Versuch soll die spezifische und absolute Ladung des Elektrons experimentell bestimmt werden. Ersteres mithilfe eines Fadenstrahlrohrs und letzteres durch den Milikanaufbau. Daraus soll dann die Masse des Elektrons berechnet werden.


\section{Theoretische Grundlagen}
    \subsection{Fadenstrahlrohr}
    Um die spezifische Ladung des Elektrons \( \frac{e}{m} \) zu bestimmen, wird ein Fadenstrahlrohr benutzt.
    Ein Fadenstrahlrohr ist ein physikalischer Versuchsaufbau bei dem beschleunigte Elektronen durch die Lorentzkraft innerhalb eines Glaskolben auf eine Kreisbahn gezwungen werden. Dieser ist mit einem Gas gefüllt welches bei Zusammenstoß mit den Elektronen sichtbar leuchtet. Das Magnetfeld wird senkrecht zur Flugrichtung der Elektronen durch ein Helmholtzspulenpaar um den Kolben erzeugt. 
    
    Um die Elektronen zu beschleunigen wird eine Elektronenkanone benutzt, die sich im inneren des Glaskolben befindet. Elektronen treten dabei aus einer Heizspirale aus und werden dann durch  eine Beschleunigungsspannung bis zu einer durchbohrten Anode beschleunigt. Ein Wehneltzylinder fokussiert den Elektronen gleichzeitig bevor dieser die Elektronenkanone verlässt. Da die Bahn der Elektronen senkrecht zum Magnetfeld der Helmholzspulen steht, zwingt die Lorentzkraft die Elektronen auf eine Kreisbahn.

    Die Geschwindigkeit mit der ein Elektron die Elektronenkanone verlässt kann durch gleichsetzten der kinetischen und elektrischen Energie (Energieerhaltungssatz),
    
    \begin{equation*}
        W_{el} = W_{kin} 
    \end{equation*}

    ermittel werden. Dabei ist \(  W_{el} = QU = eU \) und \( W_{kin} = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \).
    Daraus ergibt sich dann durch Umformung
    
    \begin{align}
        eU = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \nonumber \\ \nonumber \\
        \label{eq:equation_v}
        v = \sqrt{2U\frac{e}{m}}.
    \end{align}

    Für die Lorentzkraft gilt,
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \vec{F_L} = e(\vec{v} \times \vec{B}) = e v B \cdot \sin{\alpha},
    \end{equation*} 
    
    wobei $\alpha$ der Winkel zwischen $\vec{v} und \vec{B} ist$

    wegen \( \vec{v} \perp  \vec{B} \) folgt,
    -
\begin{figure} [H]
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{EE/4CM.png}
\end{figure}

Die Stromstärke im Quadrat ist proportional zur Spannung.\\
Mithilfe von Formel (2) lässt sich die spezifische Ladung $\frac{e}{m}$ berechnen mit


\begin{equation}
\frac{e}{m}=\frac{2U}{r^2}*\frac{1}{A_c^2I^2}.
\end{equation}



Wobei die allgemeine Gleichung der Geraden, die die Spannung in Abhängigkeit des Stroms im Quadrat für verschiedene Kreisradien beschreibt, gegeben ist durch 

\begin{align*}
U=\frac{e}{m}*\frac{r^2}{2}A_c^2I^2
\end{align*}

hierbei entspricht der Term, den man mit dem Buchstaben a bezeichnet, 

\begin{align*}
a=\frac{e}{m}*\frac{r^2}{2}A_c^2
\end{align*}

der Steigung dieser Geraden.
Dieser Term lässt sich nun zu

\begin{align*}
\frac{e}{m}=\frac{2a}{r^2A_c^2}
\end{align*}

umformen, mit dem Fehler
\begin{align*}
\Delta\frac{e}{m}=\frac{2*\Delta a}{r^2A_c^2}.
\end{align*}

Der Fehler der Steigung, also $\Delta a$,was in dem Fall der Unsicherheit der Steigung der Geraden enspricht, lässt sich mit der allgemeinen Formel
\begin{align}
s_a=\pm t* \frac{s_y}{\sqrt{\sum(x_i)^2}}
\end{align}

berechnen, wobei 

\begin{align}
s_y={\sqrt{\frac{\sum(y_i-ax_i)^2}{n-1}}}
\end{align}

und der Studentfaktor t=2 gesetzt wird.
In dieser Rechnung wurde a durch 

\begin{align}
a=\frac{\sum x_i*y_i}{\sum (x_i^2)}
\end{align}

berechnet, wobei der y-Achsenabschnitt b=0 ist, da die Ausgleichsgerade den Ursprung schneiden soll. Zudem sind die $x_i$ in diesem Fall die $I^2_i$ und die $U_i$ die $y_i$.
$s_y$ bezeichnet das Maß für die Streuung der Messwerte.

Einsetzten der Messwerte in die Formeln liefert für die jeweiligen Radien 3cm,4cm und 5cm
\begin{align}
s_{a,3cm}=3,4207=\Delta a_{3cm}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
s_{a,4cm}=32,658=\Delta a_{4cm}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
s_{a,5cm}=3,131=\Delta a_{5cm}
\end{align}

Somit folgt 

\begin{table} [H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
```

Comment: move \end{document} up until you find the place of the first error. Then check what is wrong there, and correct it.

Comment: In `Dies ergibt sich durch die Berechnung von 2*\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}`, you're missing a `}`

Comment: Replace `2*\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}` with `$2*\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$`; get rid of blank lines in environments such as `align`; replace `zwischen $\vec{v} und \vec{B} ist$` with `zwischen $\vec{v}$ und $\vec{B}$ ist`; under no circumstance leave a blank line *before* displayed equations (dozens, maybe hundreds, of offending instances).

Comment: Thank you guys so so much for your help it solved my problem very quickly!! <333

Answer (score 1):

When you get this error, it almost always means that you're missing a closing `}`. LaTeX will tell you what command it was scanning when it couldn't find the end of the argument, so that's a good starting point for finding the issue.

The line above the error will give you some context for the error (but not, alas, a line number) which can help find the location. Otherwise, moving `\end{document}` up in the file until the error goes away can be used to locate the point where the error occurs.